# how can i get the id of an emoji in reaction?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, emoji

I'm trying to get the id of an emoji in the reaction of a message but I don't know how to do it.

```
@client.event 
async def on_message(message):
    channal = client.get_channel(825523364844142601)
    embeds = message.embeds
    for embed in embeds:
        if embed.author.name in wishlist:
            reaction = get(message.reactions)
            print(reaction)
            await channal.send("yes")
        else:
            await channal.send("false")
```

context : im playing a discord's game, where a bot send an embed with the name of a character and on this embed, the bot automatically add a reaction. What i want is get the id of the bot's reaction and with the id add the same

Comment: Where is `get()` defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to get the emoji again to react. You can just add the reaction from the Emoji class.
I also suggest waiting a little bit and getting the message again because reactions won't be on the Message object immediately.

```py
@client.event 
async def on_message(message):
    channal = client.get_channel(825523364844142601)
    embeds = message.embeds
    for embed in embeds:
        if embed.author.name in wishlist:
            await asyncio.sleep(1.0) # Give time for reaction to update on cache
            message = await message.channel.fetch_message(message.id) # Update message object 
            reaction = message.reactions[0] # Get first reaction of a message
            emoji = reaction.emoji
            emoji_id = emoji.id
            await message.add_reaction(emoji) # You can just add with emoji, you don't need to get emoji again
            await channal.send("yes")
        else:
            await channal.send("false")
```

See the [`discord.Reaction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Reaction) object.